# Bases for intransitive permutations acting on finite sets

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, group-actions

Recently I was directed to the topic of minimal bases for permutations acting on finite sets via a question about stabilizer subgroup chains by Dr. Holt. While making my way through some readings on the topic, I noticed the restriction of the permutation group $G$ must always act transitively on a set $\Omega$. I wondered what the complications from a intransitive group would be so I decided to look further.

I have read [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Transitive_group) that "... For an intransitive group  $  ( G, X) $
with orbits  $  X _ {i} $,

$$ 
X  =  X _ {1} \cup \dots \cup X _ {s} ,
$$

and the restriction of the group action to  $  X _ {i} $
is transitive."

This makes sense, and my intuition tells me that a minimal base for $X$ would consist of $\sum_{i=1}^sb(X_i)$, since $G$ transitively acting on $b(X_i)$ would generate all elements of that particular orbit $X_i$, but I admit this is just a hunch. Here $b(X_i)$ denotes the minimum base for each $X_i$

However, it continues on to say that "Let  $  H $
be a subgroup of a group  $  G $
and let

$$ 
G  =  H \cup Hx _ {1} \cup \dots \cup Hx _ {s - 1 } 
$$

be the decomposition of  $  G $
into right cosets with respect to  $  H $.
Further, let  $  X = \{ Hx _ {i} \} $ **(Not sure I understand this notation)**.
Then the action of  $  ( G, X) $
is defined by  $  ( Hx _ {i} )  ^ {g} = Hx _ {i} g $.
This action is transitive and, conversely, every transitive action is of the above type for a suitable subgroup  $  H $
of  $  G $."

**Question:** If I am correctly understanding this, then by choosing an appropriate subgroup $H \leq G$ and applying $\forall g\in G$ to the right cosets of $H$ we can obtain a transitive action for all $X$. Does this mean that we can then take the steps to determine a minimal base for **this** transitive action? What is the criterion for choosing the appropriate subgroup $H$?

**Context**:"Bailey, P. (2011). Base size, metric dimension and other invariants of groups and graphs. Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, 43" makes a clear and direct relationship between minimal bases of permutations acting transitively on a set and what is referred to as the determining number of graph. I understand the
connection for a graph that is vertex-transitive, but how can we handle the cases for a graph automorphism group that has multiple orbits?

**Full disclosure:** I'm an undergrad who has likely muddied up some notation, conventions, and operations. I warmly welcome feedback.

Comment: If you like using H, then a base is a set of conjugates of H that intersect in the identity subgroup. The subgroup H is the set of elements that fix some particular point in the orbit. Conjugates of H are the subgroups that fix the other elements, so for a particular orbit, you can choose H or any of its conjugates, and that is fine. Once you've chosen one, then you keep choosing new points that aren't stabilized already to form new conjugates and a smaller stabilizer.

Comment: I liked Butler's "Fundamental Algorithms for Permutation Groups" (LNCS 559). Derek Holt's Handbook and Ákos Seress Permutation Group Algorithms are also good.

Comment: A restriction of an action to a subset isn't necessarily transitive - you must be leaving out context for your claim that it is. What does $\sum_{i=1}^s b(X_i)$ mean - what is $b$ and what does $\sum$ mean here? Your question at the end seems to be about the (categorical version) of the orbit-stabilizer theorem: if $G$ acts on $\Omega$ then $G/{\rm Stab}(\omega)\cong{\rm Orb}(\omega)$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$, given by $g{\rm Stab}(\omega)\mapsto g\omega$.

Comment: Combined with ${\rm Stab}(g\omega)=g{\rm Stab}(\omega)g^{-1}$ this shows transitive $G$-sets (up to isomorphism) correspond to subgroups of $G$ (up to conjugacy). All of my actions are left actions - change my statements appropriately for right actions. Also, $\{Hx_i\}$ is shorthand for the set-builder notation $\{Hx_i\mid 0\le i<s\}$ with the convention $x_0=e$.

Comment: Thank you both for the details and clarification. The claim that the restriction of the action to a subset is transitive is coming directly from the linked website. I've added some context (and clarified what $b(X_i)$ denotes) to show the connections I am trying to understand between minimal bases for a permutation groups intransitive actions and an automorphism group of graph that possesses multiple orbits.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not always true that you get minimal-sized base of a group with orbits $X_1,\ldots,X_s$ is taking the union of bases of the transitive induced actions on the $X_i$. That would be typically much bigger than a minimal base. The problem of finding a minimal-sized base for a general permutation group is very difficult, and you should not expect to find a nice solution. In computational work, we usually settle for a reasonably small base, without worrying about whether there might be other slightly smaller bases.

Comment: (Ah. I was responding to your first paragraph, where it sounds like you're saying *any* restriction of a group action is transitive. But the quote you give is simply saying the restriction of an action to *an orbit* is transitive, which is of course true.)